# Is this answer text with lots of extra characters above and below a bug or deliberately done?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was reading the answers to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41870/about-what-is-fake-rot13-text/41871#41871) question and one of the answers were including some strange characters/contours. Does anyone know if this is a bug or not?

[image]

Comment: You have never seen this, have you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Nope, until now :)

Comment: All I see are weird characters.. I don't see that "He comes" message

Comment: @earlz: Get a better browser. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. You can do this kind of thing with unicode. See the [source of the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/58d15758-ca29-49bf-a52a-1f2c746ce6c9/view-source) (especially try to highlight some of those characters with your mouse; you'll notice that many of them are considered *one* character). Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character.